# How does an isolated regular expression get evaluated

Tags: ruby, regex

I keep seeing this snippet everywhere, and it works! why?

```
while gets
    print if /start/../end/
end
```

How does ruby evaluate `/start/` without an Lvalue? I would expect that we would first have to store the value of 'gets' somewhere and then do

```
gets_result =~ /start/.. gets_result =~ /end/
```

So why does the snippet work?

Let me clear this up.

**How does ruby know to compare the regular expression against gets** In the snippet above at no point do I specify to ruby that the reg exp is to be compared to `gets` but it just knows. Question is how?

Comment: what do you mean by works?

Comment: The code does not work. A regex cannot be a part of a range.

Comment: It's not a range, it's a flip-flop operator.

Comment: guys please just copy the snippet into your interpreter, rather than telling me how it doesn't work. Thankyou.

Comment: this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111286/when-would-a-ruby-flip-flop-be-useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Kernel#gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) not only returns the next line, but also assign the value to `$_`.

[`Kernel#print`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-print) print `$_` if there's no argument.

The flip-flop operator (`/start/../end/`) also operate on `$_`.

Comment: Could you tell me how `$_` is related to this question. asked out of curiosity.

Comment: @ArupRakshit, Are you asking for this? https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/537ee14ff4cde6b765640a86217b7442090d1e76/parse.y#L9325

Answer (score 2):

Nice question.

*Remember:* When the `Range` operator (`..` or `...`) is used in a *conditional statement*, it does something totally unexpected: it *doesn't* create a `Range` object. Instead, it acts as a *"flip-flop"* operator.

The below code actually

```
while gets
    print if /start/../end/
end
```

by default is

```
while gets
    # gets_input I put just to make the code more expressive
    # actually the input taken using gets method applied here implicitly.
    print if  /start/ =~ gets_input .. /end/ =~ gets_input
end
```

Let me proof you. I took the help of Ruby [`Tracer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/TracePoint.html) class.

```
trace = TracePoint.new do |tp|
  p [tp.lineno, tp.event, tp.defined_class,tp.method_id]
end
trace.enable do
  while gets
    # when you type start in your console, 11 will be output.
    print 11 if /start/../end/
  end
end
```

Let me run this code, to show you my above code as a proof and also the Ruby **Flip-Flop** feature :

```
(arup~>Ruby)$ ruby test.rb
test.rb:6: warning: regex literal in condition
test.rb:6: warning: regex literal in condition
[4, :b_call, nil, nil]
[5, :line, nil, nil]
[5, :c_call, Kernel, :gets]
[5, :c_call, ARGF.class, :gets]
end # I presses **end** here.
[5, :c_return, ARGF.class, :gets]
[5, :c_return, Kernel, :gets]
[6, :line, nil, nil]
# Regexp#=~ call begin happened for /end/ =~ gets_input
[6, :c_call, Regexp, :=~]
# Regexp#=~ call end happened for /end/ =~ gets_input
[6, :c_return, Regexp, :=~] 
[5, :c_call, Kernel, :gets]
[5, :c_call, ARGF.class, :gets]
start # I presses **start** here.
[5, :c_return, ARGF.class, :gets]
[5, :c_return, Kernel, :gets]
[6, :line, nil, nil]
# Regexp#=~ call begin happened for /start/ =~ gets_input
[6, :c_call, Regexp, :=~] 
# Regexp#=~ call end happened for /start/ =~ gets_input
[6, :c_return, Regexp, :=~]
# Regexp#=~ call begin happened for /end/ =~ gets_input
[6, :c_call, Regexp, :=~] 
# Regexp#=~ call end happened for /end/ =~ gets_input
[6, :c_return, Regexp, :=~] 
[6, :c_call, Kernel, :print]
[6, :c_call, IO, :write]
[6, :c_call, Fixnum, :to_s]
[6, :c_return, Fixnum, :to_s]
# As there is a match so **if** clause true, thus 11 printed
11[6, :c_return, IO, :write] 
[6, :c_return, Kernel, :print]
[5, :c_call, Kernel, :gets]
[5, :c_call, ARGF.class, :gets]
end  
[5, :c_return, ARGF.class, :gets]
[5, :c_return, Kernel, :gets]
[6, :line, nil, nil]
[6, :c_call, Regexp, :=~]
[6, :c_return, Regexp, :=~]
[6, :c_call, Kernel, :print]
[6, :c_call, IO, :write]
[6, :c_call, Fixnum, :to_s]
[6, :c_return, Fixnum, :to_s]
11[6, :c_return, IO, :write]
[6, :c_return, Kernel, :print]
[5, :c_call, Kernel, :gets]
[5, :c_call, ARGF.class, :gets]
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `..` is a flip-flop operator. When given 'start', the condition evaluates to true, and continues being `true` until `end` is given.